# Packet Retransmission Pattern

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need a pattern for retransmitting packets over an unreliable connection. I am using a packet ID in the send which gets echo'ed back in the ACK so I can pair them. I am using C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am after an efficient retransmission design pattern. So when I send a packet over an unreliable connection I can restrans after a period of time then give up after so many tries.

Comment: Forgive my naivety, but couldn't you just use UDP, which has that built in?

Comment: @George Duckett: [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) doesn't guarantee the packets will arrive on the other side, he would need TCP for it, and that requires establishing an IP network and a build up the TCP connection first, which might not always be possible [i.e. layer 2 connections]

Comment: @amit, sorry got UDP and TCP mixed up, but your answer re. TCP needing a connection first makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have your pick of any [Automatic Repeat reQuest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_repeat_request) [ARQ] algorithm. [Selective repeat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Repeat_ARQ) will probably yield the best results, but is harder to implement, though I believe you can find an implementation for it for C#.